# hit ground values for 2d Jump 'n' e. g. groundline

Tags: java, android, math, game-physics, curves

I'm trying to programm a Android Jump 'n' Run and I'm stuck in the general logic.

I want a groundline or bottomlevel that isn't straight. It should be like a curve, or
hills and valleys (compare the Game Limbo). Is there any mathematical structure that describes such a state? I don't want to save every X-Value into an Array.

Please only give hints, no sourcecode ;)

I was already thinking about an edited sinus but in the Game it will look surreal...

Comment: I guess you should provide a graphical example of what you want to have as a collision boundary otherwise it's difficult to answer this question. Game Limbo probably has a sequence of straight lines, according to the screenshots, no real curves involed.

Comment: Great Jack, that should help me. I hadn't just realized the straight lines. That makes it more easy for me. Still the best answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some mathematical structures that can be used to describe paths.

- [**Bézier curves**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) -- neat curves
- [**Line**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_%28geometry%29) -- passes through two points (special case of a polynomial)
- [**Ellipse**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse) -- generalization of a circle
- [**Polynomial**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial) -- passes through a set of points

Comment: Thx, that was, what i was searching for.

Comment: Bezier curves..hard stuff :/

Answer (score 0):

[AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/) comes to mind. Takes care of collisions and game physics as well. Has plenty of source [examples](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.anddev.andengine.examples) and followers.